# protecting copper with benzotriazole

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I was told years ago that benzotriazole ("slightly soluble in alcohol"), when applied to a copper surface, will protect the surface from corrosion from the air ("forms a monomolecular layer on copper and silver which precludes most other chemistry, especially tarnishing"). I think benzotriazole used to be a common additive to silver polish? I recently tried this out and the treated surface was identical to untreated when exposed to H<sub>2</sub>S (boiled eggs in a sealed container). Some possibilities:

- <s>I was lied to!</s>
- The application process requires subtleties that I missed
- H<sub>2</sub>S is not "most other chemistry" and I should have tested with something else
- my container of benzotriazole from ebay isn't benzotriazole

Looking for suggestions for further experiments or alternative processes.

Comment: Benzotriazole isn't magic. Apparently it is helpful when added to lacquer or wax coatings, and also in combination with K3Fe(CN)6. There is a good 10p data sheet at https://www.copper.org/publications/pub_list/pdf/a1349.pdf

Comment: Test it's solubility in warm water. I've heard water but not alcohol. Make sure to dry thoroughly.